# A spectrahedron is a quadric cone when matrices in LMI are in $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$

Tags: convex-geometry, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality, spectrahedra, semialgebraic-geometry

I am watching a [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AevFRN5sxOU) (just at the beginning around 0:50-0:57).

The note says when $n=2$, $\mathcal{S}$ is a quadric cone; however, it seems that the professor says "a quadratic cone".

On page 31 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's textbook *Convex Optimization*, the quadratic cone is also called the second order cone.

However, I try to multiply out the formula of second order cone, I cannot obtain the definition of spectrahedra.

And I have no idea of understanding how to view a spectrahedron as a quadric cone when $n = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the linear matrix inequality (LMI)

$$\mathrm X \succeq 0$$

where $\mathrm X \in \mathbb R^{2 \times 2}$ is symmetric. As $\mathrm X$ is symmetric, we have $\binom{3}{2} = 3$, rather than $2^2 = 4$, degrees of freedom. Hence, we write $\mathrm X \succeq 0$ as follows

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12}\\ x_{12} & x_{22}\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$$

If $\mathrm X$ is positive semidefinite, then its $3$ principal minors are nonnegative,

$$x_{11} \geq 0 \qquad \qquad x_{22} \geq 0 \qquad \qquad \det(\mathrm X) = x_{11} x_{22} - x_{12}^2 \geq 0$$

Since we have a quadratic inequality, we can call the following spectrahedron

$$\left\{ (x_{11}, x_{12}, x_{22}) \in \mathbb R^3 \,\,\bigg|\,\, x_{11} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} + x_{12} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} + x_{22} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \right\}$$

the **quadratic** positive semidefinite cone. Is it actually a cone? Let's [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20z%5E2%20-%20x%20y) its surface

[image]

It looks like a cone to me.

However, what Boyd & Vandenberghe call the **second-order cone** is a cone in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ that can be encoded by the following linear matrix inequality (LMI) in $(x,t)$

$$\begin{bmatrix} t & x^T\\ x & t I_n\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$$

which produces the inequalities

$$t \geq 0 \qquad \qquad \qquad t^2 - x^T x \geq 0$$

or, alternatively, $t \geq 0$ and $\|x\|_2 \leq t$.